# Excel conditional formatting for highlighting the cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have wrote a formula for conditional formatting to highlight the days that are overdue from target date! The formula is highlighting everything after the date except for the exact number of days that it is overdue. Any suggestions?

```
=AND($D6<$F6-(WEEKDAY($F6,2)+1),K$4>=$F6)
```

[image: sample data]
Tried highlighting the days overdue, but it highlighted all the days after due date but the days it was supposed to highlight!

Comment: can you provide some example data? I'm not sure what you have in each of these cells

Comment: You should upload sample data with desired result because now it is not clear what cell represents what. But at least I think you are missing parentheses on $F6-(WEEKDAY($F6,2)+1, so should be =AND($D6<($F6-(WEEKDAY($F6,2)+1)),K$4>=$F6)

Comment: @YairMaron  I have included the image in the post. Thank you

Comment: @user11222393 I have added the image with desired results

Comment: conditional formatting work on the applied cells based on their content... looks like you have no content in the cells you're trying to apply the conditional formatting

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cover all the weeks that contains at least one overdue day, try this:

```
=AND($D6-WEEKDAY($D6,2)+1<=K$4,$F6>=K$4)
```